# Restoring default keybindings in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Restore Defaults isn't working for me.

Somehow, and I don't know how, Eclipse (Indigo) abruptly adopted a vi mode persona. I don't know if I bumped the wrong (right) set of keys or what. I have been absolutely unable to get back to the default Eclipse editing behavior.

I have repeatedly set and reset the Keys bindings to default, done Restore Defaults, changed to Emacs (which took) and back to default, exited and restarted, etc.

It still comes up in this vi mode.

What did I do, and how do I make it stop?

EDIT:

If I switch workspaces, the default Eclipse keybindings are all in place.  So I guess my backup approach is to blow everything away, and then recreate from scratch.  Which isn't actually *that* awful.

Comment: Are you using any plugin (like Workspace Mechanic) which could cause this?

Comment: Vrapper is installed, though I didn't even know that until this problem occurred.  To the best of my recollection, I stopped out of my office for a bit, came back, possibly bumped the keyboard in some nefarious manner, and found myself in vi-mode.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't have any "vi mode" or otherwise emulate vi-like behavior, so it must be the Vrapper plugin you have installed. First, have a look in Preferences to see if there is a Vrapper section listed; if so, there might be a way to disable the mode there.

If that doesn't pan out, I'd just remove Vrapper altogether. Open the **About Eclipse** dialog, click the **Installation Details** button, select the Vrapper feature in **Installed Software**, and **Uninstall** it.

Answer (score 1):

After a change in my Eclipse configuration my key bindings were screwed up. They acted as if they were experiencing keybinding conflict. Where a yellow dialog appears in the lower right hand side of the eclipse window. This is what I did to solve the key binding error. I tried reseting the key bindings to default and found this would not work. I found unbinding, apply then restore would reset the keybinding until Eclipse restart.

It's advisable to back the workspace metadata and may work differently depending on your configuration.

This is how I fixed my Key Bindings to default.

1. Back up the ~/workspace/.metadata to restore if needed.
2. Delete all files in directory ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/* **Except** the minimal configuration files needed to maintain a good configuration.

   - a. Except: org.eclipse.core.resources
   - b. Except: org.eclipse.core.runtime
   - c. Except: org.eclipse.ui.workbench
     [image]
3. Restart eclipse to check the configuration

   - a. I restored my Eclipse working sets and the rest of the defaults, but the minimum configuration worked out great.

Comment: It recurred on me. So Deleting this file seem to have duplicate key values in it and worked when removed > workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench.

Comment: So 5 years after your post, out of the blue for no apparent reason this happened to my STS. Removing workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi worked for me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to your workspace have a look at the files in the `.settings` folder in your workspace directory.

Comment: The workspace directories have no .settings directories, only a single .metadata directory containing a version.ini file.  There is the .eclipse directory in my home directory, the hierarchy of which contains scores of files. I'd done some grepping through them, but nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: If it's set, it should be in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory.  Probably org.eclipse.ui.prefs or org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to restore a certain keybinding (ContentAssist assigned to TAB). Instead of creating a new workspace (because I didn't want to lose my settings), I deleted the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench` folder in my workspace, after which I was finally able to remove the keybinding for good.